# DataView.Sort With Integer In Varchar

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a datatable with column "Test". Column "Test" contains the following values, which when sorted via `DataView.Sort = "Test ASC",` are put in the following order:

```
Data 1
Data 10
Data 11
Data 12
Data 13
Data 14
Data 15
Data 16
Data 17
Data 18
Data 19
Data 2
Data 20
Data 21
Data 22
Data 23
Data 24
Data 25
Data 26
Data 27
Data 28
Data 29
Data 3
Data 30
Data 31
```

and so on.

The expected result would be:

```
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
Data 10
Data 11
Data 12
Data 13
Data 14
Data 15
Data 16
Data 17
Data 18
Data 19
Data 20
Data 21
Data 22
Data 23
Data 24
Data 25
Data 26
Data 27
Data 28
Data 29
Data 30
Data 31
```

Is there a means to sort against the datatable to correctly sort the values in cardinal order?

Comment: Why do you have an integer in varchar?  Have you tried integer?

Comment: Extract the integer values into a separate integer column and sort by that column.  Or multiple columns if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the source of the grid you should add the following formatting:

```
foreach myNumber in numbers {
    list.add(String.Format("{0:000}", myNumber);)
}
```

This will add you values as

```
Data 001
Data 002
Data 003
Data 010
Data 011
Data 012
Data 013
Data 014
Data 015
Data 016
Data 017
Data 018
Data 019
Data 020
Data 021
Data 022
Data 023
Data 024
Data 025
Data 026
Data 027
Data 028
Data 029
Data 030
Data 031
```

More info at [String formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/).

Good Luck